# C++ Find the sum of elements between minimum and maximum element of matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

So, My program works as it should, but only if minimum and maximum element are in opposite corners.
So my question is how to iterate two-dimensional array from one certain element to another(and perhaps get rid of some nested loops). Shall I convert this array to one-dimensional?

Here's the correct work of the code:

[image: Here's correct work of the code]

And here's when something went wrong. The elements {0}{1} and {1}{1} got lost.

[image]

And here's the shortened varian of the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void matrix_count(int a[5][5],int min, int max, int min_i, int min_j, int max_i, int max_j) {
    int suma = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    if (min_i <= max_i && min_j <= max_j) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {       //iterating all matrix
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (a[i][j] == min) {       //start a new cycle when find min
                    for (int i = min_i; i < 5; i++) {
                        for (int j = min_j; j < 5; j++) {
                            if (a[i][j] == max) { i = 5; break; }
                            else if (a[i][j] != min) {
                                counter++;
                                suma += a[i][j];
                                cout << a[i][j] << " ";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (min_i >= max_i && min_j <= max_j) {} // min[i]<max[i] min[j]<max[j]
    else if (min_i <= max_i && min_j >= max_j) {} // min[i]<max[i] min[j]>max[j]
    else if (min_i >= max_i && min_j >= max_j) {} // min[i]>max[i] min[j]>max[j]
    cout << endl;
    cout << suma << endl;
    cout << counter << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a[5][5] = { 
        {0,4,6,3,5},
        {7,1,5,6,2},
        {6,8,8,5,2},
        {4,1,5,2,2},
        {4,3,6,5,9} };
    int min = a[0][0];
    int max = a[0][0];
    int max_i = 0;
    int min_i = 0;
    int max_j = 0;
    int min_j = 0;

// finding the max
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (a[i][j] > max) {
                max = a[i][j];
                max_i = i;
                max_j = j;
            }
        }
    }

// finding the min
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (a[i][j] < min) {
                min = a[i][j];
                min_i = i;
                min_j = j;
            }
        }
    }

    matrix_count(a, min, max, min_i, min_j, max_i, max_j);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "_my question is how to iterate two-dimensional array from one certain element to another(and perhaps get rid of some nested loops)._"  - please break that down a bit. - In addition: Make your code into a [mcve].

Comment: *So my question is how to iterate two-dimensional array from one certain element to another* -- Given the array type you have, it is no different than if you had a 1-dimensional array, since a 2D array has a layout of the data in contiguous memory.   It's just a matter of figuring out the starting index and ending index.  For example, that array is actually `7 6 0 3 5 7 1 5 9 2 6 8 8 5 2 4 1 5 2 2 4 3 6 5 9`.  Also, please post data as text, not as images.

Comment: `elements {0}{1} and {1}{1} got lost` It is not clear how `{0}{1}` could be considered as being "*between minimum and maximum element*". What exactly does "*between*" mean here?

Comment: FYI: I can't see anything you show as pictures. Mind sharing as pure text?

Comment: the whole program can be implemented with just a single loop, forget that it is two-dim use a pointer to traverse the matrix. Store min,max,sum while evaluating each element. There should be a bunch of if in-place to implement the logic. Since it seems to me a homework I guess I shouln’t write it, right? Good luck.

Comment: @OP -- See my answer as to how a 2D array can be treated like a 1D array -- there is no need to convert a 2D to a 1D array, since a 2D array (at least in your example) **is** a 1D array.  The only difference is that the 2D array allows you to use the `[ ][ ]` syntax to access an element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As my comment stated, one solution is to realize that the two-dimensional array has a layout of its data in contiguous memory.  Thus getting the minimum, maximum, and sum become simple, since you would traverse the two-dimensional array in the same way as a one-dimensional array.

Here is a solution using C++ algorithm functions.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    int a[5][5] = {
        {0,4,6,3,5},
        {7,1,5,6,2},
        {6,8,8,5,2},
        {4,1,5,2,2},
        {4,3,6,5,9} };

    // Get both the position of the minimum and maximum element in the array  
    auto pr = std::minmax_element(&a[0][0], &a[4][5]);

    // add up all elements between the min and max elements 
    int answer = std::accumulate(std::next(pr.first), pr.second, 0);

    // output results
    std::cout << answer;
}
```

Output:

```
100
```

Yes, that is the entire code.

So what was done?

First, we use [std::minmax_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) to traverse the array starting from a pointer to the first element (`&a[0][0]`) to one passed the last element (`&a[4][5]`).  Note the arguments to the function -- the reason why this works is that a two-dimensional array has that contiguous layout I mentioned earlier.  So it's just a matter of figuring out the starting and ending positions.

The return value of `std::minmax_element` is a `std::pair<int*, int*>` that point to the minimum element (the `first`) and maximum element (the `second`).  That is what the `pr` denotes.

Once that's done, we can quickly add up the items between the minimum and maximum elements by using [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) with the pointers we have from `pr`.

Note that the first argument to `std::accumulate` is the next value after the minimum value found.  That is the reason for the `std::next` in the first argument -- it takes us to the next value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are only iterating from `min_i` to 5. In this for statement:
`for (int i = min_i; i < 5; i++)`
This means that **every** line will start at `min_i`.

One easy way to solve this is to iterate first for the rest of the line, like so:

```java
for(int i = min_i+1; i < 5; i++) {
    if (a[i][j] == max) { i = 5; break; }
    counter++;
    suma += a[i][min_j];
}
```

And then iterate over what remains with the following loop:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = min_j+1; j <= max_j; j++) {
        if (a[i][j] == max) { i = 5; break; }
        counter++;
        suma += a[i][j];
        cout << a[i][j] << " ";
    }
}
```

But in general I would really suggest you think a bit more about your code, as all of what you are doing could be done by iterating just once over the entire matrix. Also, the first two loops that go until arriving at minimum are not only confusing (you are reusing j and i), but also unnecessary. You can directly start at `min_i+1` like in the code I showed above.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the answer has already been given, I will share my personal solution, where I'm using conversion array to the one-dimensional.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int N = 5;
const int M = 5;

void matrix_count(int a[N * M], int min , int max, int min_i, int max_i) {
    int counter = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    printf("\n\n");
    if (min_i <= max_i) {
        for (int i = min_i + 1; i < N * M; i++) {
            if (a[i] == max) { break; }
            counter++;
            sum += a[i];
            cout << a[i] << " ";
        }
    }
    else if (min_i >= max_i) {
        for (int i = max_i + 1; i < N * M; i++) {
            if (a[i] == min) { break; }
            counter++;
            sum += a[i];
            cout << a[i] << " ";
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    cout <<"sum = "<< sum << endl;
    cout << "number of elements = " <<counter << endl;
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N*M ; i++) a[i] = 0;
}

void find_min(int a_one[N * M], int &min, int &min_i) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N * M; i++) {
        if (a_one[i] < min) {
            min = a_one[i];
            min_i = i;
        }
    }
    printf("\nMin_i = %d", min_i);
    printf("\nMin = %d", min);
}

void find_max(int a_one[N * M], int& max, int& max_i) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N * M; i++) {
        if (a_one[i] > max) {
            max = a_one[i];
            max_i = i;
        }
    }
    printf("\nMax_i = %d", max_i);
    printf("\nMax = %d", max);
}
void convert_arr(int a1[N][M],int a_one[N*M], int &i_one) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            a_one[i_one] = a1[i][j];
            i_one++;
            cout << a1[i][j] << " ";
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int max_i = 0;
    int min_i = 0;
    int a1[N][M] = {
        {6,4,6,3,9},
        {7,1,5,6,2},
        {0,8,8,5,2},
        {4,1,5,2,2},
        {4,3,6,5,7} };
    int a_one[N * M] = {};
    int i_one = 0;

    convert_arr(a1, a_one, i_one);

    int min_1 = a_one[0];
    find_min(a_one, min_1, min_i);

    int max_1 = a_one[0];
    find_max(a_one, max_1, max_i);

    matrix_count(a_one, min_1, max_1, min_i, max_i);

    return 0;
}
```