# C++: Type of multidimensional array with `variable` size

Tags: c++, arrays, types

I can run this

```
int a = 5; 
auto foo = new int [a][4][4];
```

But when I try this:

```
int a = 5; 
int * foo[4][4];
foo = new int [a][4][4];
```

I get the error

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘int (*)[4][4]’ to ‘int* [4][4]’
```

#### Question

What type do I have to specify for `foo`?

Edit:
The goal is to have one single chunk of memory, not an array of pointers.

Comment: On a side note here: Multidimensional arrays, e.g `int[4][4]` are ragged by nature which might or might not be what you want This has implications in terms of performance (caching) and usually you actually want a contiguous chunk of memroy. As an example: `int arr[4*4]; int x = arr[i*4 + j]` to access element `arr[i,j]`

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann -- In that form, the multidimensional array is not ragged -- the data is in contiguous memory.  [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64723110/c-find-the-sum-of-elements-between-minimum-and-maximum-element-of-matrix/64733291#64733291)

Comment: You're confused between a 2D array of pointers (that's what you wrote) and a pointer to a 2D array (that's what you want).

Answer (score 3):

The error message is a little confusing because it does not state the variable name.

This works:

```
int a = 5; 
int (*foo)[4][4];
foo = new int [a][4][4];
```

Answer (score 2):

As @john correctly identified:

> You're confused between a 2D array of pointers (that's what you wrote) and a pointer to a 2D array (that's what you want).

So what's the difference between pointer to an array and array of pointers. The correct syntax to define a pointer to an array (what you tried to do):

```
data_type (*var_name)[array_size];
```

But this defines an array of pointers (what you actually did):

```
data_type *var_name[array_size];
```

@OP in your own answer you already found out what the correct type should be – a pointer to an array `int (*foo)[4][4]`, but I thought a little more explanation is also helpful.

Comment: This is a nice answer, *except* for the geeksforgeeks link. I suggest removing that, your answer doesn't really need it.